# How to draw a shape of polygon dynamically on map in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

how to draw a shape of polygon dynamically(not predefined **paths**) and how to store lat long values of Polygon

I already refer [AGMPolygon](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/AgmPolygon.html) but it didn't solve my isuse

Comment: You should checkout leaflet, you can easily achieve it using leaflet, [http://leafletjs.com](http://leafletjs.com)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update 26 Apr 2018.**

I am not sure but seems that the Angular Google Maps has already supported drawing polygon. You can check [more](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/AgmPolygon.html).

---

Check the working demo:

1. Basic version (drawing polygon only) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draw-polygon-google-maps
2. Updated version (drawing multiple polygon and intersect checking)  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draw-polygon-intersect?file=src/main.ts

[AGM](https://angular-maps.com/) is the best library for Angular 2 for now but It still needs to update more to reflect all the Google Maps API. So better we follow Google Maps doc and use it directly before the Angular community support it.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

Please be noted that it is a very basic one which allows you to draw a polygon and get the coordinate once finishing. You might want to move all the map related code into service as well.

Also, better to wrap the whole code within `zone.runOutsideAngular` to prevent unnecessary change detection.

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
          zoom: 8
      });

      this.drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
          drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
          drawingControl: true,
          drawingControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
              drawingModes: ['polygon']
          }
      });

      this.drawingManager.setMap(this.map);
      google.maps.event.addListener(this.drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', (event) => {
          // Polygon drawn
          if (event.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
            //this is the coordinate, you can assign it to a variable or pass into another function.
              alert(event.overlay.getPath().getArray());
          }
      });
    })        
}
```

Comment: I dont want to overlap polygons and need draggable for polygon

Comment: if possible please make not overlapped and draggable polygon

Comment: You can read the doc and try by yourself first. If you get stuck then we can help.

Comment: awarded you bounty

Comment: please provide me how to check whether polygon intersecting or not

Comment: Thank you. Not sure if you have already checked the link. One quick question, do you need to support the polygon with holes inside? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185619/determining-if-two-polygons-are-overlapping-in-google-maps

Comment: i have checked it but getting issue and not aware of JSFiddle and  JavaScript Topology Suite (JSTS)

Comment: can u please update your plunker for storing polygon in one array and validating new polygon whether it overlapped with polygon array polygons

Comment: So in short, your map needs to support drawing more than one polygon and you can also edit the polygon later. Every time, you draw a new one, you want to check If this polygon intersects with all the drawn polygon? Let's see If can help but not sure, it required some efforts.

Comment: yaa my map needed multiple polygons

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar: please check the updated answer with new plunker, simple like that. Is this your expectation?

Comment: Updated the stackblitz link, you can check it.

Answer (score 4):

Refer to this and try to implement using javascript.
The Code will be much simpler (i personally prefer this)
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools